# How to publish SQL Query result into labels

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to develop a Web Application that can print reports from an SQL Server database using some parameters that the user need to enter.

I'm using Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web.

I used the solution in the link below to do the query (to take the parameter from the textbox)
[Visual Web Developer SQL Query via Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3569565/visual-web-developer-sql-query-via-button)

Please advise what action code (Visual Basic) should be programmed on the button to publish the results on a printable form. (Not on the same page)

Application usage demo:
(1) The user logs in
(2) The user chooses the form he wants to print
(3) The user enters the parameter (in a textbox) then clicks on a (button) to get the required record
(4) The user can preview and print the published form

Appreciate your kind assistance regarding this.
Any recommendations about the programming design of the application are so welcomed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should take a look at SQL Reporting Services (SSRS), you can achieve your desired outcome and more.

Comment: From the link it seem that you are displaying query results in a DataGridview. You are more probable to get answer with asking (or searching) "HOW to make DataGridview printable?". Just a hint is to use css @media print  http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/24/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/

Comment: Thanks a lot for your kind assistance. The report builder is indeed great :)

Regarding the SSRS, is there a simple way to publish the reports designed by Report Builder for users to be able to access them through web?

The reason I need this is because I have some users who are working on Apple operating system. However, if any workaround is available, I'd really appreciate sharing it.

Thanks again and wish you all the best.